# Develop Desktop Application using Xamarin Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Is there a way i could use Xamarin Visual Studio to create a desktop application for windows. ?

Comment: Do you want to know if Xamarin technologies (such as Xamarin.Forms) can be used to develop desktop apps? It is coming for macOS right now, and would support WPF on Windows soon.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio contains a number of project templates and innumerable libraries that allow you to create just about any kind of application that you might want on Windows Desktop.